# Clicking Back Button on browser returns JSON Model of page

Tags: web8, dxa, dxa-1.5

I am using SDL Web 8.1 and DXA 1.5 for my website development. I am facing an issue on the website. While traversing the website, if I click on the back button on the browser toolbar, the previous page's JSON Model is displayed in the browser. It is happening only on some pages, not all. However, if I disable the browser cache, it works fine.

I am also not able to debug it, as the request doesn't goes back to code. Can anyone please help? Has anyone faced a similar scenario before?[image: browser developer control panel showing "Disable cache" enabled]

It happens only on the product pages of our website, which are rendered as CMS Pages.

Comment: Looks like its caching issue, try to add  "Vary: Accept" to the response header and try.

Comment: Can you **edit** your question and explain a few things in more detail? What exactly do you mean with *rendered as CMS Pages*? What browser are you using and could it be that it requests with an  `Accept: application/json` header on the back button (see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16400639/back-button-chrome-gets-json-instead-of-html-in-play-framework)?

Comment: Hi Bart, it is happening on all browsers. Also, we were not appending any response header explicitly, so not sure why this happened for certain pages. However, after pushing "Vary: Accept" to response header, all seem to work fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is browser specific Cache issue, Add  `"Vary: Accept"` to the response header and try to replicate your issue. I had resolved similar issue with above setting.

Comment: Thanks Raj, this seems to resolve the issue on my local environment. I will test it on server as well.